# Devise Async / delayed jobs - send custom emails with delayed job too?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, delayed-job

I have a solution where I be able to send the devise ' stock emails ' the mail messages that are defaultly included in Devise with Delayed jobs. In a async manner. Therefore I use the following code:

**/initializers/devise_acync.rb**

```
module Devise


  module Models

    module Confirmable
      alias_method :send_confirmation_instructions_without_delay, :send_confirmation_instructions
      handle_asynchronously :send_confirmation_instructions
    end

    module Recoverable
      alias_method :send_reset_password_instructions_without_delay, :send_reset_password_instructions
      handle_asynchronously :send_reset_password_instructions
    end

    module Lockable
      alias_method :send_unlock_instructions_without_delay, :send_unlock_instructions
      handle_asynchronously :send_unlock_instructions
    end

    module Invitable
      alias_method :deliver_invitation_without_delay, :deliver_invitation
      handle_asynchronously :deliver_invitation
    end


  end

end
```

In my User Model **devise is linked to this model** I do

```
def confirm!
    welcome_message
    super
  end

private

  def welcome_message
     ::Devise.mailer.welcome_instructions(self).deliver
  end
```

The big question that keeps me dazzled:
How would I be able to send this welcome message true delayed_job?
And how would you add other emails that are custom and not devise included so they get send true delayed_job also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing it like this:

```
def welcome_message
  ::Devise.mailer.delay.welcome_instructions(self)
end
```

Comment: stupid not tried that since its so obvious i believe it works will at least in development, thx!

Answer (score 3):

I found this to be an elegant solution - http://danseaver.com/blog/2011/10/18/sending-devise-emails-with-delayed-job

I changed it slightly to handle all the outgoing devise emails, running rails 3.0.7 + DJ 3.0.1

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
# override Devise::Mailer to use queue outgoing mail into DJ
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer

  def confirmation_instructions(record)
    Devise::Mailer.delay.confirmation_instructions(record)
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(record)
    Devise::Mailer.delay.reset_password_instructions(record)
  end

  def unlock_instructions(record)
   Devise::Mailer.delay.unlock_instructions(record)
  end
end

# Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth. The first
# four configuration values can also be set straight in your models.
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in DeviseMailer.
  config.mailer_sender = APP_CONFIG[:member_email]

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  config.mailer = "DeviseMailer"
...
```

Comment: jackquack's answer below is the better one

Answer (score 3):

Better to use [devise-aync](https://github.com/mhfs/devise-async) gem or checkout this small [blogpost](http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2013/02/how-to-send-devise-emails-via-delayed-job-or-rescue-or-any-other-background-jobs/)

Answer (score 1):

I found that none of the above worked for me. I'm using Devise 2.0.4 and Rails 3.2.2 with delayed_job_active_record 0.3.2

The way devise actually talks about doing something like this in the comments in the code is to override the methods in the User class. Thus, I solved it like so, and it works perfectly:

app/models/User.rb

```
def send_on_create_confirmation_instructions
  Devise::Mailer.delay.confirmation_instructions(self)
end
def send_reset_password_instructions
  Devise::Mailer.delay.reset_password_instructions(self)
end
def send_unlock_instructions
  Devise::Mailer.delay.unlock_instructions(self)
end
```

Comment: Check the one I posted http://stackoverflow.com/a/14799039/179855. Its working perfectly fine for me..

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite easy to do by overriding a single method on your User model.  Devise sends all emails through the `send_devise_notification` method, so just change the code there to be async-friendly.

```
def send_devise_notification(notification, opts = {})
  devise_mailer.delay.send(notification, self, opts)
end
```

This code is assuming Sidekiq, though the syntax may be compatible with Resque or DelayedJob.

Answer (score 0):

(Question is almost 3 year old, but still easy to find through Google, So here is my contribution)

Best practice is to follow Device's instruction as describe in the source https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L129

```
class User
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable

  after_commit :send_pending_notifications

  protected

  def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
    # If the record is new or changed then delay the
    # delivery until the after_commit callback otherwise
    # send now because after_commit will not be called.
    if new_record? || changed?
      pending_notifications << [notification, args]
    else
      devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver
    end
  end

  def send_pending_notifications
    pending_notifications.each do |notification, args|
      devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver
    end

    # Empty the pending notifications array because the
    # after_commit hook can be called multiple times which
    # could cause multiple emails to be sent.
    pending_notifications.clear
  end

  def pending_notifications
    @pending_notifications ||= []
  end
end
```

In which you just need to replace the 2 occurrences of

```
devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver
```

By

```
devise_mailer.delay.send(notification, self, *args)
```